# Best way to approach sending external php a variable

Tags: php, html, mysql

I was wondering if some one could direct me on the right path to take because every way I have tried has failed or really broken my code. To keep it simple I have page with a dynamically created select box populated with peoples names from a mySQL database its element id is 'insert'. This page also holds the php query

my query on the database works if I hard code a name in but I want to pass it as a variable from the select box.  I can't seem to get it to post my variable and return me an id.
heres my query

```
<?php

  function getElementById($id) {
      $xpath = new DOMXPath(NEW domDocument);
      return $xpath - > query("//*[@id='$id']") - > item(0);
  }

  $insertName = getElementById('insert');
  printf($insertName);
  $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "karaoke");

  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  $sql = "Select id FROM queue where singer = '$insertName'";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql) or die("Bad SQL: $sql");

  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $insertAt = ("{$row['id']}");
      printf($insertName);
      printf($insertAt);
  };

?>
```

whats the best way to get my variable sent to the script and then return me the answer.

thanks

Comment: PHP is server side, and DOM is in Client Side... I recommend you to use Ajax...

Comment: you try to get the content of  a form even before user see it client side so your field are empty and your sql query receive empty strings and thus fail.Use ajax as suggested by @JuliSmz.

Comment: You need to split your processing into two parts - one part to display the data to the user, and one part to capture the returned input to the user (by reading the POST variables). I suggest you find a tutorial regarding PHP and forms, it will show you the correct approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either the [`POST` or `GET` form methods](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) to send data from your HTML form to your PHP script. In the form element, you will want to set the action to your PHP script like so: `<form action = 'your_php_file.php' method = 'GET or POST'>`. This means that when the form is submitted, you can get the data from this PHP file. Then, in your PHP, you will want to use the [global variable](https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_superglobals.asp) for either `POST` or `GET` (depending on which you have used for the form method) to get the value from the select box. Using this method means you can replace your GetById function and assign the value from the form to the `$insertName` variable using the superglobals.

Another problem in your code is that you use your PHP variables in your SQL query. This means that your code is open to an SQL injection which could lead to problems such as people getting all of the database info (which is bad for a database storing poorly encrypted/hashed passwords, or even storing them in plain text)or could even lead to your database being deleted. To avoid this, you should use prepared statements and parameters whereby the statement is sent first without the variable and the variable is bound after.

Also, take a look at the links above about `POST` and `GET` and also about the PHP global variables which will allow you to get the data from your HTML form. Also, here are some links which explain prepared statements and parameters so that you can write more secure PHP code:

[Mysqli prepare statement](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) used to prepare the statement. The use of question marks are as placeholders as you later bind your variables to the query.

[Mysqli Bind Param](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) used to add in the variable to the SQL statement after the statement has been prepared which prevents SQL injection.

That's all for now, but be sure to ask any questions you may have and I will try my best to answer them all.

**EDIT**

ADDED CODE - hopefully will demonstrate what you were after, there are some small changes that may need to be made. There may be some extra code needed to fit in with any other code you have, but this should demonstrate the principle of `POST` and prepared statements with parameters. Written in OOP as opposed to your procedural as I find it cleaner and easier (personal opinion). If there are any problems integrating this be sure to tell me about any errors or issues/further questions. I too am fairly new to PHP.

```
<?php

  $insertName = $_POST['insert']; // Get the value of the select box which will need to have the attribute 'name = "insert"' by POST
  printf($insertName);
  $con = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "karaoke");

  // Check connection
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: ".mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  $sql = "Select id FROM queue where singer = ?";
  $stmt = $con->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bind_param("s", $insertName); //Binds the string insertName to the question mark in the query
  $stmt->execute();

  while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) { // Left as was because syntax is different from PDO which I use. Therefore, I am assuming this part is correct.
      $insertAt = ("{$row['id']}");
      printf($insertName);
      printf($insertAt);
  };

?>
```

Comment: TYVM this is helpful...I know it is weak but it is just running  on one machine for one person and I am just learning by getting dirty :)

Comment: I do have one question Liam as I stated in my question the html and php are currently in the same page do they need to be seperate and if not I have more then one php script on that page, will that be a problem

Comment: The HTML and PHP can stay on the same page and I do sometimes code this way. The main reason for splitting them up would just be to make the code easier to navigate. If by multiple php scripts on one page you mean more than one set of `<?php ?>` tags, they are all taken as one script and this should be fine as long as there are no crossovers in things like variable names or overwriting variables.

Comment: If you want the form to submit to the page it is on, which also contains the php code, you don't need the action part of the form tag.